# How to open a document when QR code is scanned using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

I am developing a Flutter application to scan QR code and to automatically show the document associated with it. I have some set of documents with  unique identifiers stored in Firebase storage. Once, I scan the QR code, it needs to be assigned to a identifier and then display the document.

I implemented the code to scan qr code and redirect to a url or a raw content string information using barcode_scan plugin. But I am not sure how we can redirect to a file stored in Firebase.

```
Future<void> _scan() async {
  ScanResult codescan = await BarcodeScanner.scan(),
  );
  setState(() {
    qrCode = codescan.rawContent;
  });
}
```

Comment: if your barcode scanning if successful and you get unique identifier , then fetch that document and save in local storage. if document type is pdf then there are lot of packages to open pdf document.